# Best way to create data dump when dealing with high frequency data

Tags: mongodb, database-performance, bigdata

I am developing a listener/logger to track events and later do analytics. Since the data could potentially scale to a very large size, I want to be able to split the data into chunks and store in a particular format after each hour. Now, while doing this, I dont want the DB performance to get affected.

Currently I am using MongoDB and looking at "shard key" with a possibility of using timestamp (hour resolution) to be the key.

Another approach could be to have a database replica and use the replica for creating data dump.

Please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You're 100% right about the performance

> When connected to a MongoDB instance, mongodump can adversely affect mongod performance. If your data is larger than system memory, the queries will push the working set out of memory.

and to handle the issue they have given the solution

> use `mongodump` to capture backups from a `secondary member of the replica set`.

[MongodB Docs about BackUp and Restore](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/backups/)